# AlertDialog poping up twice

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have a `fragment` in its on `createview()` method I put a condition that if this condition is true show `alertdialog` and any of its button clicked, dismiss dialog but on clicking dialog's button the dialog popup again, here is my condition and `dialog` inside it:

```
 if(getUser().isFirstTimeLogin() && getUser().getReceivedRequests().size() > 0 && getUser().getReceivedRequests().get(0).getStatus() == 0){

        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.anonymous_login_popup, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView description = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tv_anonymous_dialog_content);
        TextView okBtn = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
        TextView cancelBtn = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
        title.setText("Pending Request");
        description.setText("Your Spouse request is pending");
        okBtn.setText("Accept");
        cancelBtn.setText("Reject");
        Typeface tf = FontManager.getTypeface(getActivity(), FontManager.VARELA_ROUND);
        FontManager.setContainerTypeface(dialogView, tf);
        dialog.setView(dialogView);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.show();
        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();                   acceptRejectRequest(String.valueOf(getUser().getReceivedRequests().get(0).getId()), 1);
            }
        });
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();                    acceptRejectRequest(String.valueOf(getUser().getReceivedRequests().get(0).getId()),     2);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: is it possible the code you posted is being called twice??

Comment: are you sure there is already not two dialog ? I thing your code is calling twice .

Comment: Check if it two dialogs stacked together or pop up again right after you close your dialog?

Comment: @Jim  I have dubugged, code is not running twice

Comment: @ADM  I have dubugged, code is not running twice

Comment: @HendraWD what do you mean?

Comment: @blackHawk Could you post your code where you attach or replace this fragment?

Comment: Temporary comment this method "acceptRejectRequest" inside button click event and try !!

Comment: post your full fragment may be you are running it again on onresume

Comment: Hi. I never wrote alertdialog like you did. But i think you should dialog.create() move just before you show() dialog.

Comment: I mean is it really pop again after you dismiss your dialog, or it just simply 2 dialogs stacked together?

Comment: also make sure you don't replacing your fragment again once it get attached

Comment: @blackHawk AFAIK there is no way that two dilog will open with this code .So the thing left is your OnCreateView() is Calling Twice . So make sure you are not adding same fragment twice . just LOG onCreateView() to check .

Comment: @blackHawk what does method acceptRejectRequest do? Will the method get looped and hence Alert Dialog is pushed twice

Comment: Its just api call and noting else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always debug your code see how code is executing, in this case the code run twice and dialogs stacked up each other so dismissing upper dialog pops dialog beneath it so seems like dialogs poping up multiple time :)

Happy coding!

Comment: Debugging did the trick. Apparently, I had an onTouchListener call the performClick() action under the hood, hence I had two alert dialogs invoked.

Answer (score 3):

The way I used and work perfectly for me is to define an AlertDialog instead of AlertDialog.Builder
And I show the AlertDialog

This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.DialogTheme);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout , null);
builder.setView(contentView);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
...
//instead of builder.show()
alert.show();
```

And in on click just use `alert.dismiss();`

Answer (score 1):

As far as displaying dialog is concerned, I always set a flag like `dialogIsDisplayed`, a boolean, in the utils class. Whenever there is an event which calls a dialog, I display the dialog when this flag is `false`. Immediately, i.e after the dialog is called, this flag is set to `true`.

Inside the dialog, before calling `dismiss()`, this flag is set to `false`.

This way, creation of a duplicate dialog is prevented.